# NetBeans потерял библиотеки

Tags: winapi, netbeans, gcc

Добрый день!
Не могу понять, что случилось.
После небольшого перерыва вернулся к разработке своего проекта а собрать, заведомо работающий код не могу.
NetBeans скачал и установил какие-то обновления. После них, проект который собирался и работал, теперь выдаёт:

> undefined reference to `getaddrinfo'

я уже по всякому пробовал. и указывал конкретную библиотеку с полным путём (аля -l../../libws2_32.a) и путь к каталогу (аля -L../../lib)
без толку =(

вот пример полного вывода:

> cd 'D:\prj\projects\solutions\netbeans\tests\test_crypto_file'
>   D:\sdk\mingw\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
>   "/D/sdk/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk
>   QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf make.exe[1]: Entering directory
>   `/d/prj/projects/solutions/netbeans/tests/test_crypto_file'
>   "/D/sdk/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk
>   dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/test_crypto_file.exe make.exe[2]: Entering
>   directory`/d/prj/projects/solutions/netbeans/tests/test_crypto_file'
>   mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows gcc     -o
>   dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/test_crypto_file
>   build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/_ext/a04caf6/test_crypto_file.o
>   -L../../../../../../sdk/mingw/lib ../../common/dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/libcommon.a
>   ../../libssl/dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/liblibssl.a
>   ../../libcrypto/dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/liblibcrypto.a -lws2_32
>   -lwsock32 ../../libcrypto/dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/liblibcrypto.a(b_addr.o): In
>   function `addr_strings':
>   D:\prj\projects\solutions\netbeans\libcrypto/../../../src/openssl/crypto/bio/b_addr.c:204:
>   undefined reference to`getnameinfo'
>   ../../libcrypto/dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/liblibcrypto.a(b_addr.o): In
>   function `BIO_ADDRINFO_free':
>   D:\prj\projects\solutions\netbeans\libcrypto/../../../src/openssl/crypto/bio/b_addr.c:426:
>   undefined reference to`freeaddrinfo'
>   ../../libcrypto/dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/liblibcrypto.a(b_addr.o): In
>   function `BIO_lookup':
>   D:\prj\projects\solutions\netbeans\libcrypto/../../../src/openssl/crypto/bio/b_addr.c:681:
>   undefined reference to`getaddrinfo' collect2.exe: error: ld returned
>   1 exit status make.exe[2]: ***
>   [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/test_crypto_file.exe] Error 1 make.exe[2]:
>   Leaving directory
>   `/d/prj/projects/solutions/netbeans/tests/test_crypto_file'
>   make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2 make.exe[1]: Leaving directory`
>   /d/prj/projects/solutions/netbeans/tests/test_crypto_file' make.exe":
>   *** [.build-impl] Error 2
>
> СОБРАТЬ FAILED (значение выхода 2,, общее время: 1s)

Windows10
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101)
Обновления: Среда NetBeans IDE обновлена до версии NetBeans 8.2 Patch 1